# Elasticsearch index location in the cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 10 node elasticsearch cluster, and in this cluster the kabul index exist with 1 primary and 1 replica shard, and i want to know on what node the primary and replica shards of given index exist, how do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can run `GET _cat/shards?v&index=<index-name>` via kibana

[cat shards API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html)

Api Results (an example):

[image]

Comment: Thank you man with a strange name! it works! brilliant

Comment: :) You can accept the answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Okay! i have strange name too! my name is Plov ( Pilaf) this is traditional Uzbek,Tajik,Afghan, Azerbaijan dish